# How to draw on top of an image in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I used JFrame to import and display an image, and used mousemotionlistener to detect the mouse clicks, and I want to be able to draw on top of the image. I want to be able to, if the user makes a click, make that pixel a certain color while preserving the rest of the image, however, I couldn't find out how to use Graphics to do so without deleting the rest of the image or opening a new window.

```
public class Simple extends JFrame{
  static ImageIcon icon;
  static JFrame myframe;
  static JLabel mylabel;
  static BufferedImage image = null;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
      image = ImageIO.read(new File("mypic.png"));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    icon=new ImageIcon(image);
    myframe=new JFrame();
    myframe.setSize(200,200);
    myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mylabel=new JLabel();
    mylabel.setIcon(icon);
    myframe.getContentPane().add(mylabel);
    myframe.pack();
    Container container = myframe.getContentPane();
    MouseMotionEvents3 mousemotion = new MouseMotionEvents3();
    container.add(mousemotion);
    myframe.setVisible(true);
    while(1 == 1) {
      if(mousemotion.signal == true) {
        System.out.println("second message");
        mousemotion.signal = false;      
      }
    }
  }
}
  class MouseMotionEvents3 extends JPanel implements MouseListener,
    MouseMotionListener {
    public boolean signal;
    public MouseMotionEvents3() {
      addMouseListener(this);
      addMouseMotionListener(this);
      signal = false;
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
     // System.out.println("i hate you");
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
      signal = true;
      System.out.println("message");
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
    }
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should start with [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and the [2D graphics trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer The OP 'figured it out' in a way that clearly shows they did not follow, or understand the content of, those links. :( OP: I'd draw direct to the image. It's persistent and the code simply needs to `repaint()` the component displaying the image (`mylabel`) to display the change.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm a parent, I'm use to not been listened to :P

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend that you start by having a read through [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and the [2D Graphics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/), they will provide you with a starting point.

There are a number of ways you might achieve this, this example simply keeps track of the click points and draws dots over the top of the image

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Point> points;
        private BufferedImage image;

        public TestPane() {
            points = new ArrayList<>(25);
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/shanewhitehead/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-03-09 at 1.55.18 pm.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    points.add(e.getPoint());
                    repaint();
                }                
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return image == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (image != null) {
                g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
            }
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            for (Point p : points) {
                g2d.fillOval(p.x - 4, p.y - 4, 8, 8);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

This example draws the dots directly to the image itself...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage image;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/shanewhitehead/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-03-09 at 1.55.18 pm.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (image != null) {
                        Point p = e.getPoint();
                        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
                        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g2d.fillOval(p.x - 4, p.y - 4, 8, 8);
                        g2d.dispose();
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return image == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

In both cases, they simply make use of the `Graphics2D` API

Answer (score -2):

The simplest method would be to have a list of points that represent the pixels you wish to colour. Then override the `paint` method for the label to first call `super.paint` (to display the image) and then paint the pixels that have been clicked.

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

myLabel = new JLabel() {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        points.forEach(p -> g.fillRect(p.x, p.y, 1, 1));
    }
};
```

In your mouse handling just add the current point to the list and repaint the label.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    points.add(me.getPoint());
    myLabel.repaint();
}
```

There are more sophisticated methods that involve buffered images but this is likely good enough to get you started.

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out, I can use the getGraphics() method of the JFrame to allow myself to draw on top of the image.

edit: Andrew Thompson is right, minimizing the window removes the changes.

Comment: This is the wrong solution for a number of reasons. 1) It's best not to do painting directly in a top-level container, but instead to add a `JPanel` and custom paint that. 2) **Never use `getGraphics()` with any component!** The component might be called to repaint itself at any time (e.g. try resizing the window, or minimizing and restoring it).